# Question about the android .finish() method

Tags: android

whats the difference between MyActivity.finish() and MyActivty.this.finish()?  I see an example where MyActivty.this.finish() is called from hitting the OK button on a dialog asking if you want to exit the app.  isn't the ".this" part redundant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MyActivity.finish()` assumes that `finish()` is a static method on `MyActivity`.

`MyActivity.this.finish()` is calling `finish()` on the enclosing instance of `MyActivity`.  It's also equivalent to `this.finish()` or just `finish()` (assuming it's being called from within `MyActivity`).